# Pickling error: Can't pickle <type 'function'>

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, pickle

I am wondering what this error might mean:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

I understand that it has something to do with using multiple cores. I am running my program on a cluster and using 15 threads in this line of my code:

```
gauss2 = PTSampler(ntemps, renwalkers, rendim, lnlike, lnprior, threads=15)
```

The sampler in question is the one documented for the Parallel Tempering sampler at http://dan.iel.fm/emcee/current/user/pt/

Any idea what this error might mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569754/how-to-tell-for-which-object-attribute-pickle-fails?lq=1

Comment: I get a different exception: NotImplementedError: pool objects cannot be passed between processes or pickled.  Looks like it never even gets to the PicklingError.  This is using Python 2.7.6 and emcee version 2.1.0.

Comment: Would it serve your objective to pickle ntemps, renwalkers, rendim, lnlike, lnprior and threads, then reconstruct an identical sampler when you load the pickled file?

Comment: some similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4677012, https://stackoverflow.com/q/10898268, https://stackoverflow.com/q/16091963

Answer (score 5):

The error means you are trying to pickle a builtin `FunctionType`… not the function itself.  It's likely do to a coding error somewhere picking up the class of the function instead of the function itself.

```
>>> import sys
>>> import pickle
>>> import types
>>> types.FunctionType
<type 'function'>
>>> try:
...     pickle.dumps(types.FunctionType)
... except:
...     print sys.exc_info()[1]
... 
Can't pickle <type 'function'>: it's not found as __builtin__.function
>>> def foo(x):
...   return x
... 
>>> try:
...     pickle.dumps(type(foo))
... except:
...     print sys.exc_info()[1]
... 
Can't pickle <type 'function'>: it's not found as __builtin__.function
>>> try:
...     pickle.dumps(foo.__class__)
... except:
...     print sys.exc_info()[1]
... 
Can't pickle <type 'function'>: it's not found as __builtin__.function
>>> pickle.dumps(foo)
'c__main__\nfoo\np0\n.'
>>> pickle.dumps(foo, -1)
'\x80\x02c__main__\nfoo\nq\x00.'
```

If you have a `FunctionType` object, then all you need to do is get one of the instances of that class -- i.e. a function like `foo`.

Comment: What if you want to pickle a class?

Comment: Classes tend to work if they are user built, however they pickle by reference, so there are some limitations (e.g. they are best imported).  You can try `dill`, which makes pickling classes much easier.

Comment: I tried `dill` and I couldn't get it to work for dynamically created classes, although elsewhere I know you said it is possible. I decided that having these complicated objects is probably not the best anyhow.

Comment: `dill` should work for dynamically generated classes, in general, so if you have found cases that it doesn't please ask a SO question or post it on the `dill` github issues.

Comment: All your exceptions above say `it's not found as __builtin__.function` but the exception from the original question says `attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed`...

Comment: Obviously, yes, the exception is different. I was demonstrating that the FunctionType is not pickleable, which should be enough to help track down the issue... hard to say more given the lack of code in the post.